# JDA reaction event listener java

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to create an event listener for reactions on discord messages for a java discord bot. I haven't found any docs relating to this and my attempts have been futile, the idea is that users who react to the message are subscribed to a mailing list.

```
public class accept extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onreactionAdded(MessageReactionAddEvent event) {

        MessageReaction reaction = event.getReaction();
        ReactionEmote emote = reaction.getReactionEmote();
        MessageChannel channel = event.getChannel();
        System.out.println("test");
        channel.sendMessage("Commands:\n !notify - notifies users who have subscribed to mailing list").queue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote onreactionAdded instead of onMessageReactionAdd.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the java doc, it has all the events in it:

[ListenerAdapter#onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent)](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/hooks/ListenerAdapter.html#onMessageReactionAdd(net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.react.MessageReactionAddEvent))

you want: `onMessageReactionAdd`, hope this was useful.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code from that link into your answer?